# Woocommerce hook after a successful payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using emerchantpay for the payment gateway. Sometimes it does not redirect after the successful payment and it only happened during production. I wanted to create a fallback if that happens by using a hook which I found `woocommerce_payment_complete` and/or `woocommerce_order_status_changed`.

I've added it on my main controller to where all my hook is.

```
public function init() 
{
    add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', [$this, 'status_changed', 10, 3]);
    add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', [$this, 'woocommerce_payment_complete']);
}

public function status_changed( $id, $previous_status, $next_status )
{
    $order = new WC_Order($id);
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    var_dump('COMPLETE', $order);
    error_log('status_changed');
    exit;
}

public function woocommerce_payment_complete( $order_id )
{

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    var_dump('COMPLETE', $order);
    error_log('woocommerce_payment_complete');
    exit;
}
```

I've added a dump on each method and an error log to check if the actions were actually called but none of them were called.

Is there any way that I could trigger the hook or is there another hook that I can use to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` hook for the same

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'completed_orders', 9999 );
 
function completed_orders() {
   return 'test';
}
```